# std::set with std::pair - how to write comparator for elements

Tags: c++, opencv, c++11, stl, set

I have a `std::set` containing values of the type of `std::pair<T1, T2>` with order by first value of the pair:

```
struct Comparator
{
    bool operator() (const std::pair<T1, T2>& lhs, const std::pair<T1, T2>& rhs) const
    {
        return lhs.first < rhs.first;
    }
}
```

My definition is `std::set<std::pair<T1, T2>, Comparator> s`.

But when I try to insert pair with the same first value with element inserted to the set before (second value is different). The set does not insert it.

I'd like to have `std::set` that treats elements as equal only where second value of the pair is equal (or first and second are equal). How to do that??

P.S. I don't want to use boost library.

Comment: How does the default comparison for `std::pair` not suit your purposes?

Comment: What you've described you want and what your comparison does seem to be two different things.

Comment: @RetiredNinja, I want two things: I'd like `std::set` with `std::pair`: 1) sorting by first value of the pair. 2) treating values as equal ONLY where second value of the pair is equal (it's important during inserting elements of course). My comparator fulfills only first requirement.

Comment: A set uses the same comparison for sorting and determining equivalence.  Your needs are not a match for that.  You'll need to choose a different container.

Comment: Equality in a set is determined by the ordering. Two elements (lhs and rhs) are considered equal if `!(lhs < rhs) && !(rhs < lhs)`. (where `<` is your comparison function) So if you want a field to be taken account of when determining equality, that field needs to be taken account of in the ordering.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

> But when I try to insert pair with the same first value with element inserted to the set before (second value is different). The set does not insert it.

Well, that's what you've asked for.  Your comparator only looks at the `first` member and a `std::set` does not allow for duplicate entries.  I guess that you probably want to sort by the `first` member first and if that is equal, by the `second`.  Hence, change your comparator to something like this:

```
struct Comparator
{
    bool operator() (const std::pair<T1, T2>& lhs,
                     const std::pair<T1, T2>& rhs) const
    {
      if (lhs.first == rhs.first)
        return lhs.second < rhs.second;
      else
        return lhs.first < rhs.first;
    }
}
```

Note that this is what the default operator `<` for `std::pair` [would do anyway](http://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/utility/pair/operator_cmp) so if you want this particular ordering, simply use the default.

Comment: a.k.a. `return lhs < rhs;`, which is the behavior you will get if you just use `std::set<std::pair<T1, T2>>`, with no custom comparator.

Comment: @BenjaminLindley My main point was to explain how the definition of the comparator causes the observed behavior.  I was not sure if this is really the ordering the OP wants but the solution should be easily transferred to other orderings.  Your point is valid, though.  I'll add that too.

Comment: @5gon12eder, No. I want to have set sorted by first value of the pair. Elements of the set should by unique by second value of the pair.

Comment: Then simply reverse the check: `if (lhs.second == rhs.second) return false; else if (lhs.first == rhs.first) return lhs.second < rsh.second; else return lhs.first < rhs.first;`.

Comment: That comparison (in your last comment) is invalid, as it breaks transitivity.

Comment: @BenjaminLindley You are right, that one is wrong.  Also, it is not the “reverse”.  The initial idea was to sort by `second` and then by `first` because `second` will be unique anyway but the above logic clearly doesn't cut it.  So is it even possible to do what the OP wants?  I cannot think of any way at the moment but this might also be because I'm getting really tired now…  Thanks for pointing that out, anyway.

Answer (score 0):

Thanks for replies. So, let's make it task easier:
1) Sort ordering: lhs.first < rhs.first (so I'd like to sort by first element of the pair).
2) The set should treat pair as equal (and forbid to insert) ONLY when: lhs.first == rhs.first && lhs.second == rhs.second.

I think it's clear what I'd like to have.

I'm writing application using CV Open library. My set is defined as:

`std::set<std::pair<double, cv::Point>, QComparator> s;`

where `QComparator` is:

```
struct QComparator
{
    bool operator() (const std::pair<double, cv::Point>& lhs, const std::pair<double, cv::Point>& rhs) const
    {
        return lhs.first < rhs.first;
    }
};
```

P.S.
I'll explain what is cv::Point in CV library:

```
typedef Point_<int> Point2i;
typedef Point2i Point;
```

How to do that?

Comment: It's weird because when I try to make it in std::set<std::pair<int, int>> it works as expected...

Answer (score 0):

it seems this comparator works.

```
struct Comparator
{
    bool operator() (const std::pair<T1, T2>& lhs,
                     const std::pair<T1, T2>& rhs) const
    {
        if (lhs.second == rhs.second)
            return false
        if (lhs.first == rhs.first)
            return lhs.second < rhs.second
        return lhs.first < rhs.first
    }
}
```