# How to override the uniqueness and order of a std::set<std::pair<int, int>> in c++?

Tags: c++, stl, set, std-pair

I am trying to create a std::set of std::pair in c++. The behaviour I want the set to show is to order the pairs using the first element of the pair and to define the unqiueness using the second element of the pair. For example, if the input pairs are as follows:

```
1 5
5 2
3 3
2 4
4 3
```

The set should look like :

```
1 5
2 4
4 3
5 2
```

Comment: `std::set` can't do that.

Comment: Have a look at this one: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/27893968/stdset-with-stdpair-how-to-write-comparator-for-elements

Comment: Does this answer your question? [std::set with std::pair - how to write comparator for elements](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/27893968/stdset-with-stdpair-how-to-write-comparator-for-elements)

Answer (score 0):

You cannot do that using `std::set`. `std::set` uses the same relation of equality as it does for the order and there is no trick to change that.

Comment: Thanks for the info. Is there some other stl container that is capable of doing it, then?

Comment: @DivyanshFalodiya No. I think `boost::multi_index_container` would be capable.

Answer (score 0):

You can use a map to make the uniqueness.

```
#include <iostream>
#include <set>
#include <map>

using p = std::pair<int, int>;

int main(){
    std::set<p> s {
        {1, 5},
        {5, 2},
        {3, 3},
        {2, 4},
        {4, 3}
    };
    // copy to a map
    std::map<int, int> m;
    for(p e: s){
        m[e.second] = e.first; 
    }
    // put back in the set
    s.clear();
    for(p e: m){
        s.emplace(e.second, e.first);
    }
    // print out
    for(p e: s){
        std::cout << e.first << ' ' << e.second <<'\n';
    }
}
```

Answer (score 0):

**<kbd>[Live Coliru Demo](http://coliru.stacked-crooked.com/a/48f0f97fe3b033e1)</kbd>**

```
#include <boost/multi_index_container.hpp>
#include <boost/multi_index/ordered_index.hpp>
#include <boost/multi_index/key.hpp>
#include <utility>

using namespace boost::multi_index;
using int_pair=std::pair<int,int>;
using container=multi_index_container<
  int_pair,
  indexed_by<
    ordered_non_unique<key<&int_pair::first>>,
    ordered_unique<key<&int_pair::second>>
  >
>;

#include <iostream>

int main()
{
  container c={{1,5},{5,2},{3,3},{2,4},{4,3}};
  
  for(const auto& p:c)std::cout<<p.first<<" "<<p.second<<"\n";
}
```

**Output**

```
1 5
2 4
3 3
5 2
```